# Does Windows 7 log all file copies?

Tags: windows-7, windows

A person in our office had to put a file on a USB drive as it was too large to email. Later she found out that she shouldn't have.

Since she didn't know the company policy, she has probably copied other files in the past. Is there a way to check her computer to see which files she has copied to her USB flash drives (without having access to them)?

Comment: Sorry, this is really hard to read.  Are you asking how to find the files that were put onto the USB without the USB?

Comment: unless the admin has logs of people copying stuff on external media device its just impossible

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: There might be Windows Group Policy settings which can help auditing file transfers, if they were turned on and recording file transfers BEFORE you needed that info.  It takes a lot of log file size to record that level of granularity, so Windows doesn't turn on those sorts of logs by default.  The sysadmin of your domain should make the decision whether or not to do that for the future.

Comment: By default Windows does not log all file copies. There are built-in ways to control access to removable media, and I suggest your IT department should research and apply these if this is the policy of the organization.

Comment: @DavidPostill Actually, it isn't. Our guideline forbids issues __specific__ to corporate IT support and networks. But this question may apply to a home computer (or any other computer) as well.

Answer (score 3):

By default, no version of Windows creates a log of files that have been copied, whether to/from USB drives or anywhere else.

While I've not done so myself, it's my understanding Windows 7 does support [auditing of file or folder access](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771070(v=ws.11).aspx). If this happens to already be configured in your environment, this is likely to be your best shot at determining if the files in question have been copied.

Another, perhaps more manageable solution would be to use the Device Control features available in more advanced endpoint security products.  For example, Symantec Endpoint Protection can be configured to [restrict user access to USB thumb drives or external hard drives](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH106304.html).  This can be used to support an already in-place organization policy prohibiting users from taking digital assets without authorization.

Comment: In a domain, Group Policy can control whether or not USB storage devices can mount.   The settings are in  Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | System | Removable Storage Access     and     Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | System | Device Installation | Device Installation Restriction .

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean she's not allowed to plug in USB devices at work?

You can't see what files are on a USB drive without connecting it to some type of computer, so just use another computer/tablet/phone.

It's possible the work computer has extensive logging, maybe an administrator could find out what files were copied, you should ask the IT department at work about that.